# Is there an event to capture when the user close the compose email without having the task pane opened?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

I need to run some code when the user close the compose email either by clicking in a different email or by closing the windows, but I don't want them to have the task pane pinned, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for an event-based add-in where upon closing the email or switching to another email, the add-in gets notified so that it can execute some code to handle the event/notification. We have [Event-Based Add-Ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch) in Outlook, however, we don't have an event for closing the email or switching to another email. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) are considered when we go through our planning process.